# Sending SMTP emails reliably from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, spf

I have a Wordpress site hosted at Cloudways. I have installed their Elastic Email SMTP add on. In theory I only need to activate the add on, and then the server will take care of STMP relay and authentication. Which means I don't need a SMTP plugin for Wordpress.

I have added a SPF value of `v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.elasticemail.com ~all` 
and a DKIM value of `k=rsa;t=s;p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCbmGbQMzYeMvxwtNQoXN0waGYaciuKx8mtMh5czguT4EZlJXuCt6V+l56mmt3t68FEX5JJ0q4ijG71BGoFRkl87uJi7LrQt1ZZmZCvrEII0YO4mp8sDLXC8g1aUAoi8TJgxq2MJqCaMyj5kAm3Fdy2tzftPCV/lbdiJqmBnWKjtwIDAQAB` to my DNS settings, acording to Elastic emails own guidelines.

If send some test email trough a small PHP scrip on my server:

```
$to = "web-XXXXXX@mail-tester.com";
$subject = "Testing";
$txt = "Hello world!";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,'From: noreply@mydomain.se ','-f noreply@mydomain.se ');
```

I get excellent score at www.mail-tester.com, and the email also arrive without problems at two different inboxes of mine.

But when I try to send email from wordpress, trough the plugin "check email" I get crappy score at www.mail-tester.com... It's says I'm not fully authenticated and I get -3 minus score for this line in particular: `We didn't find a mail server (MX Record) behind your domain name xxxxxx.cloudwaysapps.com.`

How comes I get so bad score when sending test email trough Wordpress compared to a simple php test script, and what should I do to get reliable score on outgoing mail from Wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *problem* is that Wordpress has a default behavior of setting Return-Path to the server address, in my case: `xxxxxx.cloudwaysapps.com` instead of `xxxx@mydomain.com`. The solution and what also makes the email much more likely to reach an inbox is to modify the default behavior of Wordpress with this [tiny plugin](https://abdussamad.com/archives/567-Fixing-the-WordPress-Email-Return-Path-Header.html). It sets the Return-Path header of outgoing emails to equal the from email address.

Answer (score 2):

For WordPress, the actual problem is what you have identified in your second comment.

There is another workaround if you use “**WP Mail SMTP**" plugin on your WordPress site. It overrides the default WordPress email behavior with your customized settings.

Cloudways has written a complete guide on setting up [SMTP on WordPress](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/setup-configure-smtp-on-wordpress/). In their example, they have used Gmail SMTP, but the steps are same for Elastic Email.

Answer (score 0):

You can also code this very quickly in the functions.php theme file.  For example:

```
function my_phpmailer_example( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->ReturnPath='bounce_here@domain.com';
    $phpmailer->Sender='noreply@mydomain.com';
    $phpmailer->SetFrom('noreply@mydomain.com', 'My Name', FALSE);
}
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_example' );
```

In my experience, actively setting all three of these entries explicitly will really help with dkim and spf validation issues.