# Problem in SMTP setting in Wordpress live server with ProHost <unaux.com> to receive mails from Wordpress Contact Form

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp

I'm facing problem to setup SMTP into Wordpress Contact from to get mails directly in my assigned Inbox. It's showing that "Your message has sent successfully and notified sender mail...." but unfortunately it is not showing anywhere either at Inbox or sender mail ID as notification. Can you please suggest me which SMTP to be assigned at the Form configuration? Is it to be  or hosting site <unaux.com>?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending SMTP emails reliably from Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437639/sending-smtp-emails-reliably-from-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Use [WP Mail SMTP by WPForms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) and configure it properly.